# Folders don't show up in navigation, KeyError while editing them

Tags: plone

Recently we noticed that some (published) folders in our Plone 3.3.5 site are no longer visible in the navigation and folder listing views. While trying to set a new effective date (it's set in the past, so that is not the problem) on them i get a KeyError:

```
Traceback (innermost last):
 Module ZPublisher.Publish, line 125, in publish
 Module Zope2.App.startup, line 238, in commit
 Module transaction._manager, line 96, in commit
 Module transaction._transaction, line 389, in commit
 Module transaction._transaction, line 445, in _callBeforeCommitHooks
 Module collective.indexing.transactions, line 57, in before_commit
 Module collective.indexing.queue, line 149, in process
 Module collective.indexing.indexer, line 89, in unindex
 Module collective.indexing.indexer, line 71, in unindex
 Module Products.CMFSquidTool.queue, line 160, in unindexObject
 Module Products.CMFSquidTool.patch, line 24, in call
 Module Products.Archetypes.CatalogMultiplex, line 49, in unindexObject
 Module Products.CMFPlone.CatalogTool, line 445, in uncatalog_object
 Module Products.CacheSetup.patch, line 109, in uncatalog_object
 Module Products.CacheSetup.patch_utils, line 6, in call
 Module Products.ZCatalog.ZCatalog, line 569, in uncatalog_object
 Module Products.ZCatalog.Catalog, line 390, in uncatalogObject
 Module Products.PluginIndexes.DateRangeIndex.DateRangeIndex, line 192, in unindex_object
 Module Products.PluginIndexes.DateRangeIndex.DateRangeIndex, line 391, in _removeForwardIndexEntry
KeyError: -1666126693
```

In some cases other operations also triggers the same errors.

The parent folder in which this is happening was recently cut and pasted to its current location in the site, maybe that's got something to do with it.

Help much appreciated, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to rebuild the catalog, it can help, it seems there are some orphan objects in the catalog.